# Cannot find module '@angular/platform/browser'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have created my `angular2` app using `ng new myproject`, and now i am going to bootstrap my app. So here is my `boot.ts` file:

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router'

bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS] );
```

There are 2 problems in this file:
in the first line `'@angular/platform/browser'` it complains that

```
Cannot find module '@angular/platform/browser'.
```

and in the third line `import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router'` it complains that:

```
Module '"c:/Users/Salman/Desktop/Courses/Internship/Angular2/Qminder/Qminder/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'ROUTER_PROVIDERS'.
```

So how can i fix them?
Is there anything wrong with the command `ng new`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Angular Release Candidate version 4 you should import your bootstrap function from the following module:

```
import { bootstrap }  from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

The router module changed in the latest version of angular so you need to create "app.routes.ts" file which will have the following:

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

Then you need to import "appRouterProviders" and provide it to the "bootstrap" method:

```
import { bootstrap }          from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent }       from './app.component';
import { appRouterProviders } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  appRouterProviders
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

More information about the latest router can be found here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html